# subprocess using the sed command to input a variable into a specific line in a unix file

Tags: python, sed, subprocess

I'm a complete Python novice, but I need to create a small script as part of a larger project.

I'm trying to use a small Python script to input a variable into a line of code within a Unix file. I've been trying to use the `subprocess.call()` which enables me to execute the commands I need to won't allow me to place in the variable.

I have been trying the following:

```
import subprocess
var="some_variable"
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'sed', '-i', '-e' 's/line_to_replace.*/replacement_line' + var, /path/to/file.conf])
```

Comment: Why make "using sed" a part of your question, if all you want is to replace a single line of a file in the best way possible from Python?

Comment: ...in particular, the `-i` argument to `sed` is nonstandard functionality -- a purely POSIX-specified `sed` can't do what you're asking for at all.

Comment: Also, you say "specific line", but that's not what your code does: It matches by contents, not by line number; you *aren't specifying* the line, meaning that the line... well, isn't specific.

Comment: Can you explain how the script fails to do what you want it to do? If you need to run this as root, it's probably better to remove 'sudo' from the subprocess call, and instead run the python script itself as root/sudo. I'm not sure handles subprocess handles a possible password prompt when using sudo.

Comment: @HåkenLid, `subprocess` doesn't change stdin/stdout/stderr unless told to, so it has no need to "handle" any prompt; it'll be passed straight through to the console. (If the user isn't running this from somewhere with a TTY -- for instance, if this script is invoked by cron -- many `sudo` configurations will cause that to be an immediate failure, but... well, there are so many possible ways `sudo` can be configured that diving into that kind of ball of wax isn't a good use of our time).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: Including any error messages you get would tremendously help focus our efforts.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious failure here is that your code isn't putting a trailing `/` on the end of the replacement value to make it a valid `sed` command:

```
import subprocess
var="some_variable".replace('/', r'\/') # backslash-escape any sigil instances
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'sed', '-i',
                 '-e', 's/line_to_replace.*/replacement_line%s/' % (var,),
                 '/path/to/file.conf'])
```

That said, be aware that this won't work with [POSIX-standard `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/sed.html) (which doesn't have `-i`), or BSD sed (for which the extension argument to `sed -i` is not optional). The POSIX-standard tools for editing files in-place are [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/ed.html) and [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html); consider learning them.

Comment: Many thanks for your swift response.  I now have it working.

Comment: @Gooners there are also various ways of doing this just with python instead of outsourcing to sed etc. You would need a few extra lines of code, but the python script will usually be more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: Cheers,  i'll have a look at the ed and ex for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is a `sed` syntax error: You are missing the closing separator after the end of the replacement string (and the file name needs to be quoted). However, most simple Unix tools can easily be replaced with pure Python, often with immediate gains both in elegance and efficiency (avoiding an external process is frequently a significant performance improvement).

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput('/path/to/file', inline=True):
    if line.startswith('line_to_replace'):
       line = var + '\n'
    print line
```

If you genuinely need regular expression support, the change should be obvious. The `sudo` is harder to replace; perhaps you can simply run this from the prompt with `sudo` if obtaining write privileges to the file you want to manipulate is otherwise not trivial.

Comment: Might actually do the work of opening the file for output (or a temporary file and doing the mv-to-atomically-replace dance) to make this a full replacement (but for, as you say, the `sudo`).